# Custom setting of HOME and END keys on mac

Tags: keyboard

Is there a way to set the `HOME` and `END` keys on a Mac's keyboard to jump the cursor to the line's beginning and end respectively?

I tried to apply a global solution, as suggested for example [here](http://www.starryhope.com/mac-os-x-home-and-end-keys/), but this didn't help. Is there a way to do it internally in mathematica?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The file `KeyEventTranslations.tr` which can be found in the directory `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/Macintosh` couples key events to actions in Mathematica. The two lines that define the behaviour of <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> are

```
Item[KeyEvent["Home"], "ScrollNotebookStart"],
Item[KeyEvent["End"], "ScrollNotebookEnd"],
```

To change the behaviour of these two keys you could replace `"ScrollNotebookStart"` and `"ScrollNotebookEnd"` to `"MoveLineBeginning"` and `"MoveLineEnd"`, respectively.

To be on the safe side, you could copy the file to the directory `$UserBaseDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/Macintosh` first and edit that file instead of the original in `$InstallationDirectory`.

Comment: Do you know where these things are documented? And one remark, under mac, the file is located in another subdirectory named "Macintosh". Thank!

Comment: @Dror I've corrected the directory.  I don't think these things are documented very well. There is some information about the various files and directories in the installation tree in the entry `tutorial/MathematicaFileOrganization` in the Documentation Center  but that's about it AFAIK.

Comment: Putting `KeyEventTranslations.tr` in `$UserBaseDirectory/.../Macintosh` wasn't picked up on my system. I'll continue to poke at it and see if I can figure out where I should put it, but in the meantime, if you come up with something, please post an update.

Comment: @rcollyer Have you tried restarting Mathematica after making changes to KeyEventTranslations.tr?

Comment: Absolutely. I made the change, saved, shut-down mma, and restarted.

Comment: This is somehow outdated, but: http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5/FrontEnd/FrontEndTokens/ seems to contain relevant information.

Comment: Found the issue: mma saved it as a .txt file not .tr! Works now.

Comment: In case anyone else visits this answer, be sure not to inadvertently change straight quotes " to curly quotes “ ”. I edited the .tr file in TextPad and this happened, causing an error on Mathematica startup.

Comment: For shift+home and shift+end use: Item[KeyEvent["Home", Modifiers -> {Shift}], "SelectLineBeginning"], Item[KeyEvent["End", Modifiers -> {Shift}], "SelectLineEnd"],