# How to modify the file "KeyEventTranslations.tr" to use Enter to evaluate the current cell?

Tags: evaluation, keyboard

I asked the following question before, but I do not think it has been fully answered.

> By default, we use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to evaluate the current cell, and use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get a new line. Is there a way to switch the two, i.e., use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to evaluate the current cell, and use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to get a new line (like in Maple)?

The answer is related to modifying the file "KeyEventTranslations.tr," part of which is

```
(* Evaluation *)
Item[KeyEvent["Enter"], "EvaluateCells"],
Item[KeyEvent["KeypadEnter"], "EvaluateCells"], 
Item[KeyEvent["Return", Modifiers -> {Shift}], "HandleShiftReturn"],
Item[KeyEvent["KeypadEnter", Modifiers -> {Shift}], "EvaluateNextCell"],    
Item[KeyEvent["Enter", Modifiers -> {Shift}], "EvaluateNextCell"], 
Item[KeyEvent["Return", Modifiers -> {Shift, Control}], Evaluate[All]],
Item[KeyEvent["Return", Modifiers -> {Option}], "SimilarCellBelow"], 
Item[KeyEvent["Escape"], "ShortNameDelimiter"],
```

I tried many different ways to modify this file, but I never succeeded. I have many confusions about this file.

1. The first item above is `Item[KeyEvent["Enter"], "EvaluateCells"]`. It seems that <kbd>Enter</kbd> is already used to evaluate cells, but it is not. I tried to modify this line as `Item[KeyEvent["Enter"], "EvaluateNextCell"]`, `Item[KeyEvent["Return"], "EvaluateCells"]`, and `Item[KeyEvent["Return"], "EvaluateNextCell"]`, but in any case, <kbd>Enter</kbd> cannot evaluate the cell. (I am using a Windows laptop computer)
2. If I switch `EvaluateNextCell` and `Linebreak` in `Item[KeyEvent["Enter", Modifiers -> {Shift}], "EvaluateNextCell"]` and `Item[KeyEvent["Return"], "Linebreak"]` (according to Jacob's answer), then both <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> are for a line break.
3. What is difference between `EvaluateCells` and `EvaluateNextCell`? What does `HandleShiftReturn` mean? In a Windows laptop, does <kbd>Return</kbd> play a role?
4. According to the link given by Szabolcs, we can evaluate the following in a notebook.

   ```
   SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookEventActions ->
   {"ReturnKeyDown" :>
   FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluateCells"],
   {"MenuCommand", "HandleShiftReturn"} :>
   FrontEndTokenExecute["Linebreak"]}]
   ```

   This works for only one notebook in which the above command is evaluated, not for all notebooks. A puzzle to me is that even if we delete the above command, and reopen this notebook, the function of <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is still switched (only for this notebook). I wonder where this information is stored.

Could you give a clear answer on how to modify the file "KeyEventTranslations.tr"?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/OzxQ70lH2rY/rzF9Pg3vJewJ

Comment: `SystemOpen@First@FileNames["KeyEventTranslations.tr", $InstallationDirectory, 8]`, items `Item[KeyEvent["Enter", Modifiers -> {Shift}], "EvaluateNextCell"]` and `Item[KeyEvent["Return"], "Linebreak"]`. Make a backup!

Comment: On OS X, [Return] inserts a newline and [Enter], which is different key, produces evaluation.

Comment: Related (or duplicate of): [7611](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7611/57), [4094](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4094/57), and/or [6224](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6224/57) and possibly many others.

Comment: If you evaluate a cell, the cursor ismoved between the cells. And if there is another cell it will not be evaluated by "evaluateCells" but by "EvaluateNextCell" will.

Comment: @renphysics, Regarding your flag, your update only mentions Szabolcs's link. I'll try to address the questions you ask in it: 1) It works only for that notebook because it explicitly sets it only for the `EvaluationNotebook[]`. You can set it for all notebooks by changing that to `$FrontEnd`  2) These settings are stored in the object's options and persists across sessions. See `Options@EvaluationNotebook[]`.

Comment: @rm -rf, Thanks, changing `EvaluationNotebook[]` to `$FrontEnd` works. However, my original question was only the quoted part at the beginning (I edited more times), and I am highly puzzled by 1-3, because I could not find any reference to explain the file "KeyEventTranslations.tr" (modifying this file should also be a way). Also, is there a reference that explains what the things like `ReturnKeyDown` and `HandleShiftReturn` mean in 4?