# Shift+home / shift+end not working on linux

Tags: keyboard, linux

Like I said in the title: shift+home (and shift+end) key combinations don't result in selecting line from current cursor position to beginning (or end) of the line. Cursor just jumps to the beginning (or end) of the line without selecting anything. Is there any way to achieve the behavior with selection?

PS. I have configured Linux so that shift+home selecting is enabled in other applications.

Comment: It works for me without additional configuration on Ubuntu 16.04 with Mathematica 11.2. "PS. I have configured Linux so that shift+home selecting is enabled in other applications." Maybe that configuration change broke it?

Comment: I have Xubuntu 18.04.1. I turned off this changes: https://askubuntu.com/questions/57079/xubuntu-make-shiftnumpad-work-like-windows , but the problem remained.

Comment: Are you using the numpad Home or the regular Home?  I can't help here as I actually use a Mac. I tried it inside VirtualBox and I typed the Home key as `Fn`-`<-` on a Mac keyboard. This corresponds to a regular Home key. I don't know if the numpad one is any different.

Comment: This may help: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4096/12